# Is there a way to re open a connection in db4o after I used connection.close?

Tags: db4o

versant  db4o question :

is there a way to get the connection state from the connection object?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot reopen a closed container.

The only thing you can do is to check if a container is already closed:

```
 container.ext().isClosed()
```

If you want to reconnect you have the open another object container.